# Back up windows image for resintallation using bootcamp

Tags: windows-xp, osx-snow-leopard, backup

Is it possible to make an image copy of Windows XP to hard drive, so that I can reinstall it on a Mac (running snow leopard)?

Comment: If you want to be able to install Windows XP, that is, to run the program that installs Windows XP to a hard drive, you will need Windows XP installation media. As far as I know, there's no way to recreate the files needed for installation from an installed Windows XP system. If you are talking about creating an image of the Windows XP partition and plopping it on your Mac, there's not much chance that will work, since an installed Windows XP has a lot of expectations about the hardware it was installed on.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a whole page dedicated to making the "Switch" from Windows to Mac.  Part of it deals with how to setup Boot Camp.

[Switch 101: Migrate your Windows files or system to your Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2518)

Microsoft also has a page that describes how to move Windows to a new machine.  That new "machine" could just be a Boot Camp partition:

[How to move a Windows installation to different hardware](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249694)

Good luck!